# QOpenGLWidget is not updated in QMainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have loaded a QOpenGLWidget promoted into my Window class with QtDesigner, inside a QMainWindow.

The widget display is fine, I can see the obj model in my mainwindow. 
My update() function from Window is called (I know from qDebug()).

However my OpenGLWidget can't seem to be repainted inside the mainwindow unless I interact with the mainwindow (for instance, resize it, or move it on my screen). I guess these interactions imply the repaint of the whole mainwindow.

I tryied to force the repaint of the whole mainwindow everytime the OpenGL Window is updated but I can't make this work.

update() function from window.cpp :

```
void Window::update()
{
qDebug() << "update" ;

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
m_transform.rotate(5.0f, QVector3D(0.4f, 0.3f, 0.3f));
emit updated() ;

// Schedule a redraw
paintGL();
}
```

m_transform is my transformation matrix which rotates my obj model.

Redefinition of update() slot inside mainwindow.h, which is called :

```
void MainWindow::update() {
qDebug() << "update mainwindow";
this->repaint();
}
```

Connexion between signal and slot :

```
    QObject::connect(ui->GLWidget, SIGNAL(updated()), this, SLOT(update()));
```

Edit : paintGL function in window class :

```
void Window::paintGL()
{

qDebug() << "paintGl" ;
// Clear
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.2f, 1.0f);

// Render using our shader
m_program->bind();
m_program->setUniformValue(u_worldToCamera, m_camera.toMatrix());
m_program->setUniformValue(u_cameraToView, m_projection);
{
    m_program->setUniformValue(u_modelToWorld, m_transform.toMatrix());
    m_model.draw(m_program) ;
}
m_program->release();
qDebug() << "end paintGL";
}
```

I'm using Qt5.6 on QtCreator and OpenGL 3.3 on Ubuntu.

Comment: When you try to redraw your `OpenGLWidget` are you certain there's a valid OpenGL context active?  `OpenGLWidget::paintGL` should generally be invoked indirectly as a result of a call to the `QWidget::update` slot.

Comment: Do you mean that I should not call myself "paintGL()" at the end of update ? I can't remove it because paintGL() is called automatically anyway any period of time. 
I don't know how to check that the context is valid..

Comment: Actually when I remove paintGL from the update function, it is no longer called.
But I still can see my model.

Comment: Don't call `repaint()` (almost never needed and doesn't do what you think it does); don't call `paintGL()` explicitely either (it's called automatically when the GL widget needs to be repainted, calling it manually breaks it); do not call a function of yours `update()` (you're shadowing the one in the base class); do not call GL code from outside `paintGL()` and friends (otherwise you don't have a GL context). With these premises: 1) just override `paintGL()` and do your painting there; 2) if you need to *schedule a redraw* for your GL widget just call `update()` on it.

Comment: I wanted to overwrite update() so that it is called automatically. I have added my paintGL() function too (which does all the drawing), I had already overriden it. 
So what you advice is to do the animation (movement of the object) in the paintGL() function?  
I will try this.

Comment: Ok it works so thanks a lot. 
I'm surprised because when I handled my opengl window on it's own (before it was integrated to the mainwindow) my former code worked fine, with the update function. 
Could you explain why it no longer does ? (just for my personnal comprehension of it)

Comment: Your code had undefined behavior. It wasn't supposed to work, yet sometimes it did work. That's perfectly common. Undefined behavior doesn't mean that your code is guaranteed to crash. That would be **defined** behavior indeed. Your stance shouldn't be "why doesn't my code work anymore" but rather "I got lucky that it worked at all despite being broken from day one". You had broken code, you fixed it, that's all.